# Is there a way in Jenkins to stop or reduce duplicate jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that kicks off on any commit. It takes 5-10 minutes to run.

But if (say) 4 or 5 git commits come back-to-back I don't want 4 or 5 jobs run - just one job for the last commit. So basically if there is a job of type "X" in the build queue I don't want another job of type "X" in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be the default behavior if you're using the SCM trigger, default job parameters, and don't check the 'Execute concurrent builds if necessary' option.

1. First job is going to queue and run immediately.
2. On source change, next job is going to queue and wait until first one is complete.
3. A third SCM change would detect job already in queue and not do anything.
4. When first job is done, next one will start - and will use whatever is in the SCM at the moment it starts (not the moment it was scheduled).

That behavior can be changed using parameters, concurrent builds, job throttling, etc. My knowledge there might also be outdated (Jenkins is evolving pretty fast).

On a side note: multiple builds are not necessarily a bad thing - they give you failure locality, which might allow you faster identification of the offending commit. It doesn't matter much for 10 minutes builds, but if your build grows larger than that it can be a problem (with a large team, you can have a LOT of commits in 30 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just want to check if there is a new commit every 5 or 10 minutes? You can do that inside the triggering configuration: monitor source control every X minutes (CRON syntax: */15 * * * * for every 15mins)

If you check every 15 minutes if a new commit happened and your jobs only takes 10 minutes to run, there is no chance you would have another execution pending (unless someone ask for a "manual" construction...).

To avoid the latter case, you may consider the [Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin)

Comment: I like most of this, Cron Syntax should be (H/15 * * * *) so for multiple jobs and multiple jenkins servers. Also, there is a quiet period setting, turn that up to a minute or two minutes to even out commit bursts.